# DataGrid HeaderStyle overriding Header

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I have datagrid header which I populate from a viewmodel that work perfectly fine. Problem now is when I include HeaderStyle `(Style)Resources["blnGridSelectAll"];`
to have a checkbox on my header, once I include it the name of the column goes away. Below is the code to create columns

```
for (int i = 0; i<rvm.someclass.Count(); i++)
            {

                colNumber++;
                var Col = new GenerateColumn();
                Col.IsReadOnly = false;
                Col.HeaderStyle =  (Style)Resources["blnGridSelectAll"];
                Col.CellStyle = hdrStyleCenter;

                Col.Header = vm.someclass[i].Description.ToString();
                AllowancesDataGrid.Columns.Add(Col);
            }
```

XAML with the style

```
<Style TargetType="Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader" x:Name="blnGridSelectAll">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <CheckBox  IsChecked="false" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="checkSelectAll" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any idea how I can overcome this.

Comment: Please show us the definition of `blnGridSelectAll`.

Comment: @mjwills edited the question.

Comment: @mjwills the name of the column is populated from a viewmodel. I'm basically creating this DataGrid from the viemodel(someclass)

Comment: @mjwills Im showing the name directly to header     Col.Header = vm.someclass[i].Description.ToString();

Comment: Remember I cant just assign the Headerstyle a string from code behind. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to add `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>` to your template inside `<StackPanel>`, before `<CheckBox>` and see what happens. But the really bad thing here is manually creating columns like you're doing, which is **not** very _MVVM-ish_ at all.

Comment: @jstreet I agree with you its bad practice, but at this point the column names are unknown hence I had to read them directly from the viewmodel...Sometime they are 3,4,1 or even six so I had to loop and check

Comment: By default, the `Datagrid` will take the header names from each property being bound to its columns. Why don't you start with the default behavior, get things working, and THEN, try to customize it if necessary?

Comment: And even if you need to customize your headers, adding columns like that is definitely **not** the way to go.

Comment: Post your view model if you want to get any meaningful help.